# cannot find module "express" - Node.js installation on Plesk, managed by Phusion Passenger

Tags: node.js, passenger, plesk

I have enabled node.js on one of my domains on a shared server. All management actions are done from the console of Plesk Obsidian 18.0.20. I see that Plesk manages nodejs through Phusion Passenger 6.0.6.

I am unable to create an express server. The startup of my nodejs app fails with the message:

```
The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web application through 
a Passenger-internal helper tool called the "wrapper". 
But Passenger was unable to execute that helper tool because it encountered 
an internal error.

The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:

......./loader.js:xxx
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- ......../server.js
- ...../passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js
.....
.....
```

The first line of my `server.js` file contains the instruction:

```
const express = require('express');
```

I know I should access the running nodejs environment and issue the command:

```
npm install express
```

But I do not see how to do it, neither from the Plesk console nor from the putty window of my user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. The root of the problem is that Plesk expects the package.json file to be in the domain root. Instead it was in a subdir.

I also found later this tutorial: https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/